# Cómo prorratear un valor en el tiempo desde MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla mysql con los siguientes datos:

```
IDOrder, mediumint(8), unsigned, autoincrement
Total, decimal(8,2)
Meses, tinyint(2)
Created, timestamp
```

Es muy fácil obtener las ventas mensuales en una query, agrupando por el MONTH del campo timestamp, pero lo que yo necesito es prorratear los ingresos entre los meses, ejemplo:

```
Para los siguientes valores:
IDOrder | Total | Meses | Created
1       | 3,000 |   3   | 15/01/2023
2       | 8,000 |   2   | 04/04/2023
3       | 2,000 |   2   | 09/02/2023
```

Mi expectativa es que los 3,000 de enero se dividan 3 meses, a partir de enero, o sea, 1,000 para enero, 1,000 para febrero y 1,000 para marzo. Los 8,000 de abril se dividan en 2 meses, que son 4,000 en abril y 4,000 en mayo. Los 2,000 de febrero se dividan en 2 meses, 2,000 en febrero y 2,000 en marzo.

```
Mi respuesta esperada es esta:
Enero | 1,000
Febrero | 2,000
Marzo | 2,000
Abril | 4,000
Mayo | 4,000
Junio | 0
...
...
```

Agrupando por el mes, se obtienen los totales del mes, pero eso no es lo que quiero, por lo que esta query no me da el resultado experado:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(Created), SUM(Total) FROM orders GROUP BY (MONTH(created))

Respuesta incorrecta:
    Enero | 3,000
    Febrero | 2,000
    Marzo | 0
    Abril | 8,000
    Mayo | 0
    Junio | 0
```

¿Alguna sugerencia, por favor?

Comment: ¿Has intentado resolverlo? agrega lo que hayas hecho o investigado al respecto. Por otro lado ¿Siempre el prorateo es de 1 mes a enero de ese año?

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta para que sea más fácil de entender... el prorrateo comienza en el mes que se compra y durante los próximos X meses... más allá de ese ejemplo que solo me da los totales, no tengo idea cómo hacerlo desde MySQL, si pudiera hacerlo desde frontend, pero el performance se vería afectado.

Comment: No necesitas una query, necesitas un proceso.. una query, trabaja fila a fila o con conjuntos.. vos aca, tenes un poco de magia...

Comment: No habrá manera de hacer un SUM con un CASE dentro o algo así???

Comment: capaz podrias con alguna funcion ventana, usar el prorrateo, pero no se como lo guardarias en los meses que corresponden....

Comment: Esta query está cerca de lograr lo que quiero, pero algo le falta:    SELECT SUM(IF(1 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses, Total, 0)) AS Enero, SUM(IF(2 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses, Total, 0)) AS Febrero, SUM(IF(3 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses, Total, 0)) AS Marzo, SUM(IF(4 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses, Total, 0)) AS Abril, SUM(IF(5 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses, Total, 0)) AS Mayo, SUM(IF(6 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses, Total, 0)) AS Junio FROM test;

Comment: ya encontré la solución, gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDLR: **[Te dejé un fiddle para que pruebes el resultado final](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbmAysuhVi3buMWSdRbhfp/6)**

**Explicación**

Teniendo esta tabla de base

| id_order | total | meses | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 |
| 2 | 8000 | 2 | 2023-04-04 |
| 3 | 2000 | 2 | 2023-02-09 |

Yo me ayudaría de una query auxiliar para generar en cada fila tantas filas como meses deben repartirse las ventas. Un simple correlativo

```
with correlativo as (
  select 0 as contador union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
 )
```

Con eso, hacer un join entre la tabla auxiliar y la de ventas. El join tiene la condición de que el correlativo sea menor al campo "meses". Con el valor `contador` puedo computar el mes al que se asigna la fracción del total:

```
 with correlativo as (select 0 as contador union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5)

 select id_order,
        total / meses AS ventas_parciales,
        meses,
        created,
        MONTH(date_add(created, interval contador month)) mes_asignado
   from ventas
   join correlativo ON contador < ventas.meses
```

El resultado sería:

| id_order | total | ventas_parciales | meses | created | mes_asignado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 | 1000.0000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 | 1 |
| 1 | 3000 | 1000.0000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 | 2 |
| 1 | 3000 | 1000.0000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 | 3 |
| 3 | 2000 | 1000.0000 | 2 | 2023-02-09 | 2 |
| 3 | 2000 | 1000.0000 | 2 | 2023-02-09 | 3 |
| 2 | 8000 | 4000.0000 | 2 | 2023-04-04 | 4 |
| 2 | 8000 | 4000.0000 | 2 | 2023-04-04 | 5 |

Y con eso ya puedes agrupar por `mes_asignado` para llegar al resultado final

**Edit**:

Me quedé pensando en que esa solución tiene una debilidad. A la vuelta de un año los meses se repiten, así que la salida de `mes_asignado` no puede ser numérica. Debiera ser el primer día del mes de asignación. Entonces, donde decía

```
 MONTH(DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL contador MONTH)) mes_asignado
```

Ahora dirá

```
 DATE_ADD(
      DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL contador MONTH ),
      INTERVAL 1 - DAY(
         DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL contador MONTH)
      ) DAY
  )     mes_asignado
```

(sales ganando porque ahora es mucho más fácil de leer. Jo jó.)

Con eso, la salida es:

| id_order | total | ventas_parciales | meses | created | mes_asignado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3000 | 1000.0000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 3000 | 1000.0000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | 3000 | 1000.0000 | 3 | 2023-01-15 | 2023-03-01 |
| 3 | 2000 | 1000.0000 | 2 | 2023-02-09 | 2023-02-01 |
| 3 | 2000 | 1000.0000 | 2 | 2023-02-09 | 2023-03-01 |
| 2 | 8000 | 4000.0000 | 2 | 2023-04-04 | 2023-04-01 |
| 2 | 8000 | 4000.0000 | 2 | 2023-04-04 | 2023-05-01 |

Comment: Excelente explicación y funcionalidad... me quedé con tu query, ya estaba usando mi solución, pero evidentemente la tuya es mejor, gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución en una sola query, pero ahora estaría ver si es la mejor manera de hacerlo:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(1 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses - 1, Total/Meses, 0)) AS Enero, 
SUM(IF(2 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses - 1, Total/Meses, 0)) AS Febrero, 
SUM(IF(3 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses - 1, Total/Meses, 0)) AS Marzo, 
SUM(IF(4 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses - 1, Total/Meses, 0)) AS Abril, 
SUM(IF(5 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses - 1, Total/Meses, 0)) AS Mayo, 
SUM(IF(6 BETWEEN MONTH(Created) AND MONTH(Created) + Meses - 1, Total/Meses, 0)) AS Junio 
FROM orders;
```

Gracias por su tiempo.